# Update ng-show when a scrollbar becomes visible or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scrollbar, angularjs-ng-show

My goal is relatively simple. I want to be able to show a button within there is a scrollbar on a `<ul>` list.

To do that, I add the following JQuery plugin to check if there is a scrollbar on my list :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.width();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This code works well, so I put a call to this `hasScrollBar()` function in a method of my controller like that :

```
$scope.hasGoTabButtonToBeDisplayed = function() {
    return $("#tabset>ul").hasScrollBar();
}
```

And I use the `ng-show` directive to show my button only if there is a scrollbar on my list :

```
<button type="button"
 class="btn btn-xs" 
 style="float:left;" 
 ng-show="hasGoTabButtonToBeDisplayed()" 
 ng-click="onGoLeftTabButtonClicked()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

When I load the page, the button is displayed or not if there is a scrollbar on my list but if I resize my window and the scrollbar appears, the display of the button does not change, which means my `hasGoTabButtonToBeDisplayed()` method is not called. I understand why this method is not called, because Angular cannot be able to detect a change in this one but I don't know how to do that.

Perhaps I have a wrong logic to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I find a solution. I don't know if this is the best solution or even a good one but it seems to work.

So to solve my problem, I simply catch the resize event of my window in my scope and I call the `$scope.$digest()` method like this :

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
    $scope.$digest();
});
```